# Get WPF Control's validation status

Tags: wpf, validation, textbox, behavior

Good evening,

I have a PhoneNumber class with the parts of the phone number separated (area code, prefix, suffix) and I validate the textboxes by length and invalid area codes.  I want to create a behaviour that auto-tabs to the next control when the current one is valid.  I *could* hard code the capability in the codebehind by bypassing, but I would much rather user data validation and behaviors to do it consistently and re-use the ability.

I am running into a problem however, trying to get the TextBox controls validation state.  Where can you find that?  If there is a way to get that value, is there an associated event for its changing?

## Control Style which hooks up Validation

```
            <Style x:Key="ToolTipValidation" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource StandardErrorValidationTemplate}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

Obviously, when the control has the error template applied, then it has an error.  For whatever reason, the Behaviour ErrorHandler is not picking it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `Validation.HasError` attached property. Also there is `Validation.Error` event that you can handle.

**Update:**

You can subscribe to the `Validation.Error` event in code-behind like this:

```
Validation.AddErrorHandler(myTextBox, OnValidationError);
```

In the error handler can look like this:

```
private void OnValidationError(object o, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added)
    {
        // on error added logic
    }
    else
    {
        // on error removed logic
    }           
}
```

Comment: I may be missing something,  I can't find Validation.Error.  I do see Validation.ErrorEvent, but that is a routed event, and my AddHandler statement tells me ErrorEvent is not an event of System.Windows.Controls.Validation.

Comment: OK, so I implemented AddErrorHandler.  My controls are now validating, but the handler is never being hit whether the control is validated or not.  I will post my Style which triggers validation above if that helps.

Comment: @CodeWarrior you have to set NotifyOnValidationError true